# When creating entity with keyValue options, Orion auto data type detection does not infer location attribute correctly

Tags: fiware-orion

When creating an entity you could do it like this :

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://my.api/v2/entities/?options=keyValues' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
   "id":"vehicle:WasteManagement:1",
   "type":"WasteManagement",
   "vehicleType":"lorry"
}'
```

Or without the options=KeyValues parameter :

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://my.api/v2/entities/' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
   "id":"vehicle:WasteManagement:2",
   "type":"WasteManagement",
   "vehicleType":{
        "value": "lorry"
    }
}'
```

And in both case the entity is the same.
But I don't manage to create an entity with a options=keyValues parameter with an entity that has a 'location' attribute : when doing

```sh
curl --location --request POST 'https://my.api/v2/entities/' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
   "id":"vehicle:WasteManagement:3",
   "type":"WasteManagement",
   "vehicleType":"lorry",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -0.56832066,
            47.49576
        ]
    }
}'
```

In this case, the result from curl --location --request GET [https://my.api/v2/entities/vehicle:WasteManagement:2'](https://my.api/v2/entities/vehicle:WasteManagement:2%27)

Would be

```sh
"location": {
    "type": "StructuredValue",
    "value": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -3.164485592,
            40.627851337
        ]
    },
    "metadata": {}
},
```

And the type of location is `StructuredValue`

My expectation would be `geo:point` or other geo:XXX depending of the type of the GeoJSON which allow the entity to be geolocalized and filter by location.

Comment: It seems third culr has a typo. It should include `?options=keyValues`. Otherwise Orion returns: `{"error":"BadRequest","description":"attribute must be a JSON object, unless keyValues option is used"}`. I'd recommend to edit the question post to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [NGSIv2 specification](http://telefonicaid.github.io/fiware-orion/api/v2/stable/) section "Partial Representations":

> Attribute/metadata `type` may be omitted in requests. When omitted in attribute/metadata creation or in update operations, a default is used for the type depending on the value:
>
> - ...
> - If value is an object or array, then `StructuredValue` is used.

In the case of request

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://my.api/v2/entities/?options=keyValue' --header 'Content-Type: application/json' --data-raw '{
   "id":"vehicle:WasteManagement:3",
   "type":"WasteManagement",
   "vehicleType":"lorry",
    "location": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
            -0.56832066,
            47.49576
        ]
    }
}'
```

the `location` attribute fulfills with the *"when [attribute type] omitted in attribute/metadata creation or in update operations"* of the NGSIv2 spec. In addition, value is an object so *"If value is an object or array, then `StructuredValue` is used"*  applys. Thus, it is correct that the attribute is created/updated with type `StructuredValue`.

The workaround is pretty easy: don't use the keyValues mode if you need attributes with a special type (as the ones for a location or `DateTime`) and use the normalized mode instead.

Note that the keyValues mode has been designed as a *helper*  not as a replacement of the normalized mode. The keyValues mode covers a great degree of the normalized mode functionality, but not fully.